# C# REST API / Мапинг параметров запроса на свойства объекта

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Есть **Web API**-приложение.

Есть **Action**, который ловит запрос:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GetOrder(OrderRequest request)
{
    return ResponseHandler.GetResponse(Request, ActionHandler.Order(request));
}
```

Есть **Model** с описанием свойств запроса:

```
public class OrderRequest
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

В клиенте, который отправляет POST-запрос параметр `Description` передается как `$Description`, соответственно, когда запрос попадает в `Action` автоматически мапится только поле `OrderId`, а параметр `Description` остается пустым.

Как в `OrderRequest` для свойства `Description` указать, что оно должно мапится на `$Description` в запросе?

Можно ли это сделать атрибутом у свойства `Description`?

И если можно киньте статью с теорией как делается подобный мапинг, сам не нашел

Comment: Вот здесь описан Refit https://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/310704/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

```
public class OrderRequest
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE:

Контроллер:

```
//Controllers/OrdersController.cs
using System.Web.Http;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class OrdersController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public string GetOrder(OrderRequest request)
        {
            return string.Format("OrderRequest(OrderId='{0}', Description='{1}')", 
                request.OrderId, request.Description);
        }
    }
}
```

Модель:

```
//Models/OrderRequest.cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class OrderRequest
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("$Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Проверка на Postman е:

[image: Проверка на постмане]

Comment: не работает....

Comment: проверил на asp.net 4.6.1 - работает, потом проект перевел в 4.5 тоже работает

Comment: добавил более детальную информацию

Comment: проверил сам Postman'oм если отправить как JSON то действительно всё ок, но в текущей реализации клиента становится ясно, что запрос отсылается не в JSON, отправляется обычным постом с формы x-www-form-urlencoded - в этом случае ваш вариант не работает

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29090053/4594225

Comment: NullReference на этой строчке var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(qsParam).AttemptedValue;